# Asp.Net MiddleWare vs HttpModules

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Starting with Asp.Net 5 we now have the "middleware" concept to change or interact with the request and response. All of this was done before using HttpModules.

So here my question.

What is exactly an asp.net middleware and what issues are addressed by this component that can not be addressed with HttpModules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpModules` act as request filters in ASP.NET versions prior to 5. They are reusable units of code that can be plugged into the request pipeline, and tasked with responding to events defined in the `HttpApplication` class as they are fired.

`Middleware` can be thought of as both `HTTP modules` and `handlers` that we've had in classic ASP.NET. Some middleware would implement various intermediate tasks when processing requests such as authentication, session state retrieval and persistence, logging and so on. Some of them would be the ultimate request handlers that would produce responses.

---

### *Ques 2* : what issues are addressed by this component that can not be addressed with HttpModules?

- In an `HttpModule`, you had to execute code based on the various
  stages of a request, things such as `AuthenticateRequest`,
  `AuthorizeRequest`, `PostResolveRequestCache`, and other slightly
  confusingly named events. *This is no longer the case with Middleware,
  things just make sense now. everything is simply a linear execution
  of your code. You can have multiple middleware’s defined to execute
  in your application and each one is registered explicitly in your
  Startup.cs file.*
- As a developer, you are in full control of what get’s executed and in
  what order instead of not knowing which HttpModules are executing and
  not really in control of their order of execution. Middleware can
  simply modify a request and continue calling the next one in the
  chain, or it can just terminate the pipeline and return a result.

[Reference](http://dzimchuk.net/post/understanding-aspnet-5-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

Both are used to set up the request processing pipeline.

The **MiddleWare** components, we use to set up the request processing pipe line for ASP.net core application.

The **HttpModules** , we use to set up the request processing pipe line for ASP.net Application.

It is the pipeline which determines how to process the incoming httprequest and out going httpresponse.